# Socketio and cloudflare

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I've already done my research and figured out that socket.io only works with cloudflare if you use set ports found that [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-)

So through that research I found that http and https can't use the same port. I'm coming here to as you guys how do you get a socketio server to listen on two ports? So it can support http and https with cloudflare

Answer (score 1):

The common method is referred to as an SSL Termination Proxy (also called SSL off-loading). The proxy accepts incoming messages over HTTPS and passes the decrypted requests to another resource (another server, web service/API, etc.). This would allow your Node.js application utilizing socketio to handle all requests, no matter if the client made an HTTP or HTTPS request. Software like NGINX, Apache, and even Microsoft IIS are capable of providing this functionality.

Here are some links regarding this topic:

- General Info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy
- NGINX: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-ssl-termination/
- NGINX: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-tcp-ssl-termination/
- HAProxy: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-ssl-termination-with-haproxy-on-ubuntu-14-04
- IIS: https://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/ssl-off-loading-in-application-request-routing